# How to open the SharePoint server for public user access (through internet)

Tags: sharepoint-server, networking

I have my company SharePoint, so i need to open this SharePoint for the public users from the outside. How would i do it ? Do i need a public IP address or can it be done by just adding an Alternate Access mapping from the SharePoint ? Please guide me to proceed. I am using SharePoint 2013. Any Help is appreciated. I am very grateful if it is a step by step guide.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes Public IP is a must also you have to configured your router with port forwarding to.**.

**http://mroffice365.com/2011/10/how-to-open-a-sharepoint-2010-website-for-internet-access/**

**above article might help you to get this thing done.**